# Remove huge Buy Now button from all product pages

Tags: magento2.3.1

been struggling with finding a solution for this, seems like it should be an easy configuration change.  All the products on my site have a huge BUY NOW button under the Add To Cart that is for the PayPal integration, I'm trying to get rid of that Buy Now button or at least make it the same size as the Add To Cart.[image]

Comment: You can follow this link https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/How-to-remove-PayPal-from-Product-Page-Check-out-with-PayPal/td-p/134955 and remove that button from Product Page.

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable in the Paypal frontend configuration settings, or you can go to Stores > Configuration > Sales - Disable Smart Buttons